# Typgloss small capitalization on glossing third line

Tags: linguistics, linguex, cgloss4e

I use a package called `typgloss` to automatically put into small capitals linguistic glosses that are in uppercase.

The problem is that it works when there is only one line to gloss, but does not work when there are to lines to gloss. Do you have a solution to that please

I am using `linguex` along with `cgloss`. The `typgloss` package is here : https://github.com/tpellard/typgloss

Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linguex, cgloss}
\usepackage{typgloss}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\a.
\gll      à   pjě    =lè     kǔ\\ 
         AFF hare =INDF3.SG  die\\
         \glt `Hare died.'\\
\b.
\glll      à   pjě    =lè       kǔ\\  
           à   pjě    =lV        kǔ\\
           AFF hare =INDF3.SG  die\\
           \glt `Hare died.'\\





\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice little package. The author didn't add support for three line glosses, but it's easy to do.

#### Code explanation:

The `cgloss` (and `cgloss4e`) packages define macros corresponding to a word within a glossed line: `\eachwordone`, `\eachwordtwo` and `\eachwordthree`. The `typgloss` package adds a wrapper `\grlbl` to those macros which then does a regex replacement of uppercase characters with the small caps, and formats them according to the chosen `\eachword...style` (where `...` is `one`, `two` in the original code.)  I simply added the third line wrapper and corresponding style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex, cgloss}
\usepackage{typgloss}
\newcommand{\eachwordthreestyle}{}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\eachwordthreestyle\grlbl}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\a.
\gll      à   pjě    =lè     kǔ\\ 
         AFF hare =INDF3.SG  die\\
         \glt `Hare died.'\\
\b.
\glll      à   pjě    =lè       kǔ\\  
           à   pjě    =lV        kǔ\\
           AFF hare =INDF3.SG  die\\
           \glt `Hare died.'\\

\end{document}
```

Note that the way `typgloss` works, it doesn't catch single letter abbreviations like the `V` in your `lV` gloss in the second line of example (1b). If you want this kind of abbreviation to also be turned into small caps you need to surround the single letter in `{}`.

[image: output of code]

Comment: Waou ! That's fantastic. Thanks. It works now. Could you please explain the lines you added?

Comment: @SiluéLacina I've added an explanation now.

Comment: @SiluéLacina I've also created a pull request on the repo to make this change part of the package.

Comment: Thanks ! It is kind.